# Scikit-learn precision_recall_fscore_support multi-class

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to get the precision, recall and fscore for multi-class classification with scikit-learn. My classes have labels 0 and 1 but this is NOT binary classification. The scikit precision_recall_fscore_support() method assumes that my classification is binary and reports results only for class 1. If I convert my labels to string then it requires pos_label. If I provide pos_label='1' then again it reports results only for class 1.

How do I make it consider '0' and '1' as two independent classes and show me averaged results for both, not just 1?

Comment: >But this is NOT binary classification
Then what kind of classification it is?

Comment: It's a multi-class classification.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is argument pos_label=None.